# DSpace 6.3 performance and use of DB

Tags: hibernate, dspace

We are upgrading to Dspace 6.3, and having performance problems.
For example, switching on strengths makes home page load in 5 seconds and 
the loading of the page pointed to by "Create New Group" tab in JSPUI Group Editor takes around 5 minutes.

Detailed analysis shows that the time is mostly wasted into querying the database an enormous amount of queries over one connection, and the natural question that comes to mind is whether Hibernate is caching well. Hibernate reports the following after loading the "Create New Group" page.

```
2019-01-23 14:20:50,952 INFO  
org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener @ Session Metrics {
494000 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
245527100 nanoseconds spent preparing 20333 JDBC statements;
7450426100 nanoseconds spent executing 13294 JDBC statements;
6791542000 nanoseconds spent executing 7039 JDBC batches;
273618000 nanoseconds spent performing 14103 L2C puts;
116900 nanoseconds spent performing 26 L2C hits;
38389200 nanoseconds spent performing 7051 L2C misses;
113577100 nanoseconds spent executing 2 flushes (flushing a total of 26592 entities and 87312 collections);
244366925500 nanoseconds spent executing 7053 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 47154144 entities and 47154144 collections)
}
```

We have approximately 4000 collections+communities and 6000+ groups (many of them system generated).

Anybody has an idea if this is a hibernate issue or something else and how to increase performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can be related to https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-4098

Comment: Thanks, Adan, what do you mean in the bug you reported?  is that because validity is not set well, hibernate will need to re-do all queries?

Comment: The validity system force all the queries that hibernate's lazy-loading should save